# How to design a database-Excel connection for read-write by multiple users?

Tags: mysql, concurrency

In my project users maintain data in Excel tables (with proper row and column
headers). With time however, the Excel tables get pretty large.
The amount of numerical data is not too large (~10mb per person over a year),
however because the data is stored on their own computers, it gets lost say
when they leave or after a project ends.

I know that Excel provides **ODBC** drivers for most Databases. Right now, I am
trying to develop a prototype to demonstrate that the data can be stored on a
central server where multiple people can directly read and write from. To keep
things simple, I was just planning to write some VBA/Python code based on
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768327/4752883), which would take the row and
column based data from a specific sheet and dump it in the database. There are other ways to do it as
well, such as using using a direct connection to MySQL (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_kn71R9BL0)

However, I see a problem here. Say `userA` and `userB` pull data the `tableA` from the MySQL database into Excel. `userA` makes a change to the table (creates `tableB`) and writes it to the `MySQL` database using the macro. At the same time, `userB` also has the same table open in Excel. He makes a change to the table (creates `tableC`) and writes to the same row and
column of `userA`. This would lead to overwriting `userA`s data. This is not intended behavior, as ideally `userB` would know
that the database has been updated by `userA` (similar to how when co-authoring
is enabled in a Excel workbook shared in OneDrive). However, during my
research, I didn't see a obvious manner by which `userB`s Excel instance would
immediately update and notify `userB` when the data in the MySQL database is updated by `userA`.

These are 2 ways I can think of for overcoming the issue:

1. Lets assume `userA` has already updated their `tableB` to the MySQL database. When `userB` attempts to write their version of the table (`tableC`) to the database using the macro, instead of blindly writing to the table, first check if there is any existing data in that row and 
   column of the table in the MySQL database. If there is, then warn `userB` that there is new data in the MySQL database which hasn't been updated in his
   instance of Excel. Then fetch the data from the server into a separate
   worksheet (`SheetB`). Then, they can update the main sheet/table to be pushed  in `Sheet main`from the extra data in `SheetB`. The excel macro keeps a record that `userB` has updated their Excel macro in the last 5 mins (for example), and if they have, it assumes its ok to overwrite the MySQL table with `userB` s version of the table.
2. Lets say we have a starting table, `tableA` in the database. `userA` pulls
   from the MySQL database into the Excel workbook. Then then modify the table (create `tableB`) and push the data to a separate table `tableD` (where `tableD` is the differential between `tableA` and `tableB`). `userB` pulls from the
   database and makes changes (creates `tableC`). When they push from `tableC` to the MySQL database, they create `tableE` , which is the differential between `tableA` and `tableC`. Both
   `userA` and `userB` can make changes to their individual tables `tableB` and
   `tableC` as much as they want, for a certain period of time. At periodic intervals the delta `tableD` and `tableE` are appended on to `tableA` (using MySQL events https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html). In this scenario, neither `userA` or `userB` would be able to change anything that was already present in the table when they pulled from the MySQL database in the first instance, but they can append to the table.

I can see that this is going to get more complicated, if there are more users. However, it seems to me that this issue should be pretty common and must have been
solved in databases. I have come across the `file-locking` but I don't see how
it solves the problem of not overwriting `userA`s changes.

### Question:

Is Option#1 or Option#2, the best we can do or is there more sophisticated
techniques(already inbuilt into SQL database) by which mutliple users can read and write to a database from Excel,
or other app?

---

Just to provide some more details to address @danblack and @Hila-DG's answers, one of the other requirements is that all the data from different users also need to curated into a central location, so that somebody who maynot be working on a specific worksheet and if they have proper access can run some job on that data as well.

Comment: Sounds like you need a cloud based spreadsheet editing system (Google, Office365, others?) more than a database.

Comment: @danblack, thanks for your comment. If we do use the Excel workbooks in a cloud based editing system, what would be the best practice to get the data into a central location from all users, so as to be able to do some kind of ETL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good question, you've obviously done your research. The solution isn't to use Excel since Excel *doesn't have write-back capabilities!*

I am going to elaborate on @danblack answer:
You need a cloud based spreadsheet editing system, (google, office 365, dropbox, other)
The Cloud Based Spreadsheet will be shared among the relevant stakeholders
When a cloud based spreadsheet is updated it is updated across the board. If user A added something and User B added something then both changes are maintained. If user A add something and User B delete that same row then you can see the changes and ask them to clarify, etc .

Think about it this way: if your problem sounds simple you need to find a simple solution

Comment: appreciate your response.. yeah, actually that was my first recommendation. The reason I was thinking of storing the data in a database is because, when we keep the data in cloud based excel sheets, there will be 100s of such excel sheets over time stored at different locations. We also need to get the data entered in a specific table into a location from which somebody who didn't create the spreadsheet can do some kind of ETL or create models.

Comment: To solve this problem I was thinking maybe I could create workbooks for each individual/groups in very specific OneDrive location for each group. Then run a nightly cron job to pull data from those excel workbooks into a central database, if the workbooks are not open. Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: @alpha_989: only issue would be you have to be very specific what are the allowed columns in the Excel spreadsheet. People have the tendency to add a column in the end for their own calculations, etc. If you're using the spreadsheet for the basis of the ETL process then that's a different story

Comment: Makes sense. Yeah.. For the particular sheet in the users excel workbook, from which the data will be uploaded to the database, I was planning to create a more "strict" table, such that users can't add tables without headers etc (maybe using some kind of form).